# IsEmpty function with a hierarchy and date in filemaker pro 11

Tags: filemaker, is-empty

I have been using an `IsEmpty` function that I got from [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068139/using-isempty-function-in-a-filemaker-pro-v9-calculation-with-multiple-fields).

```
Case (IsEmpty(Field1 & Field2);Field3;IsEmpty(Field1);Field2;Field1)
```

However, I am now pulling from 5 fields instead of just 3 and I am trying to sort by date of visit.

My database deals with client and pregnancy tests and the fields I'm pulling from are from their exit intention after visit 1, visit 2,...visit 5.

Each visit has a different title (PT, RT, CC...etc). If the come for visit PT, US, FU and I want to pull the intention from FU or if they come in the order of PT,FU, US I'd like to pull the intention from US.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. It might be worth taking a few minutes to re-write a more general question including: the sort of table structure you have (all information is on one client record or each visit is a separate record), how is the order of the appointments known? (Are PT, RT, etc. date fields?) and what value you're trying to populate. My initial guess is that you just want Max(DateField1; DateField2; DateField3; ...) but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest method is simply to rewrite your function as follows, this should be easier to maintain than you current code:

```
Case(
    not isEmpty(Field1); Field1;
    not isEmpty(Field2); Field2;
    not isEmpty(Field3); Field3;
    not isEmpty(Field4); Field4;
    Field5
)
```

I don't think there is a built-in way to do this type of calculation in Filemaker, *if there were many more than variables you could consider writing a custom function looping through these fields until there is a non-empty entry... (provided you had Filemaker Advanced).*

Comment: That actually works perfectly. Does this sort it by date at all? It seems like it would pull from the most resent info but I just want to double check.

Comment: It's difficult to know precisely what you want, but perhaps `Max(Field1; Field2; ...)`, perhaps you can give some example rows in your question?